# my flutter app doesn't open authentication link

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am using firebase authentication and facebook authentication to facilitate users auth.
But when I click the button for face book auth it stops loading and nothing happens.

[image: Screenshot]

and in the release mode the link doesn't open.
I have tried all youtube videos to make facebook auth work.

This is my source code:

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
    // Trigger the sign-in flow
    final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    // Create a credential from the access token
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return _auth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the chrome tab that opens and seeing if there are any errors there?

Comment: @tomerpacific it works on chrome and the link works

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have already updated their api for signin options.

try reading this links it might help

ff:
[https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth]

[https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-facebook-login-77fcd187242]

![and also for the fb api i have use a webview to fetch it and send the request to the post]